# Как сделать интервал между Toast?

Tags: java, android, android-toast

У меня в коде toast вызывается бесконечно, но я хочу чтобы он вызывался условно каждые 20 секунд. Как я могу это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно создать отдельный `AsyncTask`, который будет через каждые n секунд показывать `Toast`. Переменная `boolean showToast` отвечает за цикл, пока она `true`, тосты будут всплывать.

```
class ShowToastTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try{
            while (showToast) {
              TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
              getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                   "Toast msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
                   toast.show(); 
                } 
              });

            }

        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

Вызвать его можно на пример в методе `onCreate()`

```
ShowToastTask toastTask = new ShowToastTask();
toastTask.execute()
```

Comment: окей, булевую переменную как я понял должен я создать и делать ее тру сразу после вызова Toast или до вызова?

Comment: До вызова сделать true. А когда захотите остановить выполнение таска, то сделайте её false

Comment: Понимаю, что может быть надоел вам своей тупостью но сейчас я добавил в вопрос ваш код и лог ошибок который происходит когда я его использую

Comment: Исправил ответ, ошибка возникала из-за того, что пытались вызвать тост не из UI потока.

Comment: Среда пишет, что не знает метода getActivity() а когда заменяю  getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { на  this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { или  DecodeActivity.class.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { то не  знает метода runOnUIThread

Comment: Если вы объявили класс как внитренний внутри активити, то попробуйте просто runOnUiThread(...)